# De-mining in Red Alert 1

Tags: command-and-conquer-red-alert

I've been playing Command and Conquer Red Alert 1 and can't figure out how to get rid of enemy anti-personnel mines without sacrificing one of my armoured units. How do I do it?

Comment: It's been a long time since I last played Red Alert 1. Have you tried shooting the mines? You can force your units to shoot something by clicking while holding the Ctrl key down. You can destroy bridges that way.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've played Red Alert 1, but I'm fairly certain you just force-shoot the ground where the mine is, just like @Nolonar said.

Comment: @Nolonar awesome!!! I don't know any of the hot keys so that might work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you can shoot mines by holding the ctrl key when selecting a target. Holding the ctrl key forces units to fire at selected targets. 
Thanks to Nolonar for the info!

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this on ore, since you can't force-fire on it...